# I have this error when calling Facebook's Marketing API "Api call cannot be made if api is not set". How can I fix this?

Tags: python, facebook-marketing-api

Title says it all. I am trying to connect the Facebook's Marketing API but am encountering the error above. I am a real rookie with all of this and would appreciate any help, guidance, or tutorial links.

```
from facebook_business.adobjects import campaign

adcampaign = campaign.Campaign('xxxxxxxxxx')
params = {
   'date_preset': campaign.Campaign.DatePreset.last_7d,
}
insights=campaign.Campaign('xxxxxxxxxx').get_insights(params=params)
print(insights)
```

This is the exact error message "facebook_business.exceptions.FacebookBadObjectError: Api call cannot be made if api is not set"

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize your facebook object. According to the [README](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-python-business-sdk#bootstrapping) of the python project, you need to call `FacebookAdsApi.init` first:

```
FacebookAdsApi.init(my_app_id, my_app_secret, my_access_token)
```